# Prove that a plane containing the line intersects the region in $ \mathbb{R}^3 $

Tags: calculus, analysis, vector-spaces

Consider the usual Euclidean space $ \mathbb{R}^3 $. Let $ R $ be the region $ R = \{(x, y, z) | x, y, z \geq 0 \text{ and } xy \geq z^2 \} $ and $ L $ be the line $ L = \{(x, y, z) | x = 0, z = 1 \} $. Let $ P $ be a plane containing $ L $. Show that $ P $ intersects $ R $.

Here is my thought: $ P $ is a plane, so one of its coordinates is fixed. If $ z $ is fixed, then for sufficiently large $ x, y \in P $, we will have $ xy \geq z^2 $. But I'm stuck with the case when either $ x $ or $ y $ is fixed. I'm not sure what information I can get from the hypothesis that $ P $ contains the line $ L $.

Answer (score 1):

If you think about it, $L$ sits on top of the $y$ axis at $z=1$ (with $x=0$).
Hence there are various planes containing it (think first of the plane $P = \{(x,y,z)|z=1\}$ then imagine rotating it through $360$ degrees about $L$.

Let us imagine that $P_\theta$ makes an angle $\theta$ with $P_0$.

What is the equation of the plane $P_\theta$?

The $z$ coordinates and $x$ coordinates of points on the plane will satisfy $\tan \theta = \frac{z}{x}$.

Hence our $P_\theta = \{(x,y,z)|z=x \tan \theta\}$

Finally how can we intersect this with $R$?

We ask that for some $z \geq 0$, $xy \geq z^2$. We consider $z>0$ We know that $x = z/\tan\theta$, and that $z>0$.

Then we have $y/\tan\theta \geq z$.

Hence $y = z\tan\theta$ will do the trick. I.e. the coordinates $(z/\tan\theta,z\tan\theta,z)$ will work.